# Java program runtime error ArrayIndexOutofBounds

Tags: java

Heres my code. I'm not sure whats wrong.  My project is to create a program that checks if a word is a palindrome.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PalindromeChecker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Open Scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Prompt User for word
        System.out.println("Enter word to check if it is a Palindrome:");
        // Scan in the word
        String word = input.nextLine();
        int a = 0; // used to extract word from array (small)
        int b = 0; // used to extract word from array (large)
        int c = 0; // used to stop when
        int d = (word.length());
        int e = d / 2;
        int f = e - 2;
        int x = word.length(); // set cap of array pulling
        char[] array = word.toCharArray(); // create array of chars
        if (array[a] == array[x] && c != f) {
            a++;
            x--;
            c++;
        } else {
            b = 1;
        }
        if (b == 1) {
            System.out.println("This word is not a Palindrome!");
        } else if (b == 0) {
            System.out.println("This word is a Palindrome!");
        }
    }
}
```

The error is at the

```
if (array[a] == array[x] && c!=f)
```

I'm not exactly sure what went wrong but when you put in a non-palindrome it skips over.  I'd be more than glad to have some advice as to what to do in this situation.

Comment: Would be nice if you named your variables.

Comment: @schmosel Got it.  One sec.

Comment: Where is the loop you should apply to check array characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because arrays are 0-based, the index of the last entry is length -1.

```
int x = word.length() - 1
```

You are also missing a loop for checking all the characters in a word. And finally, you seem to have a lot of redundant variables. Here's how you could fix your code:

```
    boolean isPalindrome = true;
    for (int n = 0; n < array.length / 2; n++){
        if (array[n] != array[array.length - n - 1]) {
            isPalindrome = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isPalindrome) {
        System.out.println("This word is a Palindrome!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("This word is not a Palindrome!");
    }
```

Comment: I tried this.  It solved most problems but now when I used racecafr (I got this from a typo) it doesn't work.  Do you have any other advice?

Comment: You only check the first and the last letter. You should use a loop to check all.